# Rails 4 ActionMailer Create and send email from form

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, actionmailer, sendgrid

I am new to actionmailer and can't seem to get ActionMailer to work and route properly, not sure if I'm doing it properly and most tutorials only show how to generate a generic email after a user has first created an account.

What I am trying to do is allow a user to generate an email through a form to send an email message with a link to a view to their clients to view an invoice.

My current error is due to some routing issues but the strange thing was that it's looking for an email template in my controller instead of the mailer controller is my assumption... `Missing template invoices/send_invoice_email, application/send_invoice_email`

Here is my form which the user would use to build the email.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag url: '/send_invoice' do |l| %>
     <%= l.hidden_field :invoice, value: @quote.id %>
          <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="from"><i class="fa fa-envelope"> </i></span>
            <%= l.text_field :from, hide_label: true, value: current_user.email %>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="to"><i class="fa fa-user"> </i></span>
                      <%= l.text_field :to, hide_label: true, value: @quote.client.contacts.first.email %>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="cc"><i class="fa fa-users"> </i></span>
                      <%= l.text_field :cc, hide_label: true, placeholder: "cc:" %>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="bcc"><i class="fa fa-users"> </i></span>
                      <%= l.text_field :bcc, hide_label: true, placeholder: "bcc:" %>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="subject"> <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i></span>
                    <%= l.text_field :subject, hide_label: true, placeholder: "Subject" %>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="message"> <i class="fa fa-comment"></i></span>
                    <%= l.text_area :message, hide_label: true, placeholder: "Message", rows:"5" %>
          </div>
          <%= l.submit "Send", class:'btn-u btn-u-blue btn-block' %>
<% end %>
```

My controller method in my invoice controller (this is only a show controller, Quote is created in quote model)

```
def send_invoice_email
quote = Quote.find(params[:invoice])
InvoiceMailer.send_invoice_email(quote, params)
end
```

And here is the method in my invoice mailer

```
def send_invoice_email(quote, params)
@quote = quote

mail(
to: current_user.email,
from: params[:from],
content_type: "text/html",
body: params[:body],
content_type: "text/html",
subject: params[:subject],
content_type: "text/html"
)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few things and now it seems to be working... Not sure why but I'll take it. Here are my current configurations..

Form is the same.

In my invoice controller I now have

```
def send_invoice_email
  quote = Quote.find(params[:invoice])
  InvoiceMailer.invoice_email(quote, params).deliver_now
end
```

In my invoice mailer I now have

```
def invoice_email(quote, params)
  @user = quote.user
  @quote = quote
  @message = params[:body]
  mail to: params[:to],
      from: @user.email,
      body: @message,
      subject: params[:subject],
      content_type: "text/html"
end
```